# Is there are equivalent @After or @AfterClass Annotations In The Silverlight Unit Test FrameWork for Windows Phone 7

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I am using Jeff Wilcox's [unit test framework](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/) for Windows Phone 7 (based on Silverlight 3) and was wondering what class annotations are available in this library. Besides `[TestClass]`, `[TestMethod]` there is `[TestInitialize]` which marks a method to be run before each test.

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify a method that is run after each test, such as junit's [`@After`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html)? Also are there other annotations available to developers? I haven't found anything with my google searches.

Thanks,
Alasdair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available attributes are described in the MSDN documentation for the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244252.aspx). You use the `[TestCleanupAttribute]` to mark a method to run after each test. You can also use the `[ClassInitialize]` and `[ClassCleanup]` attributes for

Comment: Thank you. Slightly embarrassed that I missed that. Even ReSharper was trying to help. Cheers.